# Does anyone know how Jake Sully was able to bond with Leonopteryx?

Tags: plot-explanation, avatar

In the *Avatar* movie, Jake was able to bond with the Great Leonopteryx.

Does anyone know how is it possible?

Comment: Could you be more specific? As far as I remember Na'vi were able to bond with many different creatures and plants.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong I think the OP is asking why did the Leonopteryx allow jake to bond with it, when no Na'vi had managed it for so long.

Comment: Because movie? He's the hero of the story, and it makes him looks cooler than any other Na'vi. It's the typical [White Stallion trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhiteStallion)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are obviously theories, but...

## Jake Earned The Leonopteryx's Respect

The Leonopteryx is referred to as the apex predator in the skies of Pandora,

> ***GRACE***
>
> The Great Leonopteryx is **the apex aerial
>   predator.** Not only rare, but the
>   sightings tend not to get reported.
>   Trudy makes a clicking motion with her thumb.
>
> **TRUDY**
>
> There usually isn’t time to key the mike.
>
> **JAKE**
>
> The People call it Toruk.
>
> **NORM**
>
> (translating)
>   Last Shadow.
>
> **JAKE**
>
> Last one you ever see.

and it never looks up because it knows there is nothing to challenge it from above.

> ***JAKE*** (V.O.)
>
> The way I had it figured, Toruk is the
>   baddest cat in the sky. Nothing attacks
>   him. So why would he ever look up?

Jake comes up with his plan to use this as a weakness. He gets above the Leonopteryx and dives down towards it.

> FROM ABOVE -- THE SMALL SHADOW of Jake’s banshee falls across
>   the back of the mighty Toruk.
>
> 117.
>
> **JAKE** (V.O.)
>
> But that was just a theory.
>   JAKE DIVES and WE RUSH DOWN toward the great beast and our
>   own shadow then --

Jake lands on the Leonopteryx's back taking the Leonopteryx by surprise. The Leonopteryx has just been bested in its own territory, so when Jake attempts the bond, it submits, knowing that Jake is worthy and the union will be beneficial.

## Eywa got involved

You also have *Eywa* - the Great Mother at work on Pandora, we see her attempting to influence things with the *woodsprites*

[image: Woodsprites]

It maybe that Eywa helped Jake to bond with the Leonopteryx by giving a little nudge to the great beast.

## The Leonopteryx "knew" the Toruk Macto was needed

The Leonopteryx being released at the end also suggests the bond was only needed for as long as the Toruk Macto was needed, with the defeat of the RDA the Toruk Macto was no longer needed and thus the bond could be severed. Did the Leonopteryx know that Pandora needed it and thus allowed the bond with Jake to take place?

It may be that all of these played a part, some of them or none.

Comment: Assumes a lot, but I like this theory.

Comment: I agree with all the above theories, I would like to include this point as well. Creatures will bond only with the Na'vi, who attack them. Like the Great Leonopteryx has attacked the Jake just after he bonds with his first Leonopteryx.

Answer (score 2):

> How was Jake was able to bond with the Great Leonopteryx?

Jake was inhabiting the body of a Na'vi....or at least a body that was *genetically identical* to a Na'vi and therefore had the abilities inherent to all Na'vi which include bonding with the Pandoran fauna.

As for the Great Leonopteryx, there is no information on how Jake *specifically* was able to bond but bonding is not unknown...but it is *rare*.

[**Wikia**](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Leonopteryx)

> At the time of Jake Sully's introduction to the Omaticaya, no Na'vi had accomplished this for four generations and **only five have managed that feat since the time of the First Songs. Jake becomes the sixth person to bond with the creature**.

Comment: Genetically **similar**, not identical.  As I recall, the movie states that the body was a blend of driver and alien DNA.  Also, unlike *true* Na'vi, Jake has 5 fingers.